# Java Web Service - List vs Array

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rpc

I'm new to web service. I'm writing some simple web services for testing and I have the following questions.

The website [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXRPC4.html) says that JAX-RPC supports array of primitive types. But when I write a simple web service

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC)
public interface AddNums {
    @WebMethod
    public int addNumbers(int[] nums);

}
```

and generate the client code from wsdl i get the following WS client interface.

```
@WebMethod
@WebResult(partName = "return")
public int addNumbers(
    @WebParam(name = "arg0", partName = "arg0")
    IntArray arg0);
```

It generates IntArray class having the member protected List

```
public class IntArray {

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected List<Integer> item;
```

Is this how the arrays are supported? So, the only way to pass the array is to create an instance of **IntArray** and set **List** of **Integers** to it?

Also when i make the webservice to **Document** style

The WS client interface from WSDL has the following method:

```
public int addNumbers(
    @WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "")
    List<Integer> arg0);
```

The **int[ ]** array in the original service, became **List< Integer>**

Does this mean that Array type in the web service is always converted to List in the client code generated from wsdl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JAX-WS use JAXB to binding. The default mapping for `<sequence>` is a `List`. But you can use `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation to provide a [custom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/j2schema.html) mapping of XML content.

You can see more about JAXB in [Introduction to JAXB (The Java Tutorials > Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB))](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/index.html)

In another hand, you can try returning an array. See the answer for the question [I can't return array String[] with JAX-WS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14083593/870248). But maybe you should consider: look at this question: [Can you return an array from a JAX-WS @WebMethod?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1499324/870248).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Could you please answer my other question related to JAX-RPC. The documentation says that JAX-RPC supports Arrays and it doesn't support Collections. But in case of JAX-RPC the int array becomes the class 'IntArray' with a member variable List.